# Gnome-screenshot. How to return old behavior?

Tags: gnome-screenshot

I have Ubuntu 18.04 now and gnome-screenshot 3.25.0
Earlier I had Ubuntu 16.04

In 16.04 after pressing print screen a window appeared with two buttons `Copy to clipboard` and `Save as`. Now it saves screenshot automatically into `~/Pictures`. It is sooo inconvenient when I want to copy and paste it from clipboard. How can I return old behavior back?